# ZoDb Persistent class broken

Tags: python, persistence, zodb

I have defined a Zodb persistent class called "Contract".

```
class Contract(Persistent):
    # list of all my orderbooks key'ed by timestamp
    def __init__(self):
        self.books= OOBTree.BTree()
```

When I load instances of this class in my 2nd python app with Zodb, I can see that there is a problem with the class. The import lines are in the 2nd app:

```
from persistent.list import PersistentList
from persistent import Persistent
from BTrees import OOBTree
```

Here is the output at runtime:

```
<persistent broken __main__.Contract instance '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x17'>
```

If I do a "print dir()" in the same context I see further broken classes.

```
['__Broken_Persistent__', '__Broken_initargs__', '__Broken_newargs__', '__Broken_state__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribut
e__', '__getnewargs__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__implemented__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__providedBy__', '__provides__', '__reduce__', '_
_reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_p_activate', '_p_changed', '_p_deactivate', '_p_de
lattr', '_p_estimated_size', '_p_getattr', '_p_invalidate', '_p_jar', '_p_mtime', '_p_oid', '_p_serial', '_p_setattr', '_p_state', '_p_status', '_p_sticky']
```

Is Contract broken due to other broken classes? Why is Persistent broken even if it is imported.

Comment: Are you using ZEO?  If so, ZEO process might need to be able to access your code/package for import.

Comment: No, I am not using ZEO. My app is a simple python app and I am using Zodb 3.3.